# Wait for the variables to fully load in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, vuejs2

**What the code is about ?**

Below is the code block from my app where the code reaches to the web and fetch the HTML data of a site for **scraping**. I've used `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com` to get the HTML data and cheerio to **scrape** the required data from the HTML blocks.

```js
import axios from "axios";
import cheerio from "cheerio";
import {
  getJobTitle,
  getOrgImage,
  getOrgName,
  paginate,
  getLocation
} from "./Helpers";

let jobTitles = [];
let imgs = [];
let orgsNames = [];
let locations = [];
let forState = [];
let bucket = [];

const state = {
  jobs: []
};

const getters = {
  meroJobs: state => state.jobs
};

async function getFromNextPage(status) {
  if (status !== null) {
    let res = await axios.get(
      "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://examle.com" + status
    );
    let chunk = cheerio.load(res.data);
    callHelpers(chunk);
  }
  return;
}

const callHelpers = html => {
  if (html !== null) {
    jobTitles = jobTitles.concat(getJobTitle(html));
    imgs = imgs.concat(getOrgImage(html));

    orgsNames = orgsNames.concat(getOrgName(html));

    locations = locations.concat(getLocation(html));

    let status = paginate(html);

    getFromNextPage(status);
    forState = makeObject(jobTitles, imgs, orgsNames, locations);
    bucket = bucket.concat(forState);

    console.log(bucket.length);
  }
  return;
};

const makeObject = (jobs, img, org, locations) => {
  let mjobs = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
    mjobs.push({
      title: jobs[i],
      img: "https://example.com" + img[i],
      org: org[i],
      location: locations[i]
    });
  }
  return mjobs;
};

const actions = {
  async fetchByQuery({
    commit
  }, param) {
    console.log("clicked");
    console.log(param);
    let response = await axios.get(
      "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://example.com/search/?q=" +
      param
    );
    console.log("Response got");
    let html = cheerio.load(response.data);

    callHelpers(html);

    commit("setMeroJobs", bucket);
  }
};

const mutations = {
  setMeroJobs: (state, jobs) => (state.jobs = jobs)
};

export default {
  state,
  getters,
  actions,
  mutations
};
```

**Does this code works ?**

Yes, the code works all fine. It does gets the HTML data and **scrapes** the required data.

**What is the issue then ?**

In the above code block we can see that I'm loading data of variable `bucket` to the state to to display in the frontend. The variable `bucket` itself is getting data in `if` statement of `callHelpers` method which is being called multiple times.

Although I've made a method to check the pagination and get data and load data to variable `bucket` from each page. But I'm getting the data in my front from the first call/iteration only [Data from first page only].

How do I wait until all data are loaded in `bucket` so that I can display them in the frontend.

**Do you have a working link ?**

I'm running the app in local machine but here is the replica of the my app in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-lewin-mlvmh?file=/src/store/modules/MeroJob.js:0-1892)

Enter `teacher` for no pagination **1 page, 4 datas**, `manager` for pagination **3 page, 18 data**

Comment: Inside of `callHelpers()` is the only place in your code where you know the variables are properly set.  So, you either use them from in there or wrap the rest of your code in a function and call that function from there.  That's how asynchronous code works in Javascript.  You have to use the results of an asynchronous call inside the callback associated with the completion of the asynchronous operation or inside some function you call from there.  There are no other ways around that.

Comment: If you want to call `getFromNextPage()` multiple times, then you need to keep track of when you're done accumulating data and start your final operation from within the completion callback of the last time your're calling it and you need to know that all of them are done.  That requires properly design your code for sequencing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies at `callHelpers` in `fetchByQuery` - You only call this once and ensure you commit the bucket afterward.

One of many ways to solve this in where I can see, is to update your code in which it should wait until `callHelpers` finishes its job, then commit the `bucket`.

Note that what I mean by `callHelpers` job is, it's to iterate through all the pages and populate all the data.

https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-butterfly-vs9ek?file=/src/store/modules/MeroJob.js

Comment: Searching two parameters `teacher` and `react` without refreshing the app shows results from both search. I did placed ` state.jobs.length = 0;
    bucket.length = 0;` and `state.jobs=[ ]; bucket = [ ]` before axios request inside `fetchByQuery` method but didn't help. Do I need declare another action to action and set mutation for this ??

Comment: @PawanRai If you don't want to keep concatting the result, you may **empty** the `bucket` at the beginning of your search call.

Comment: I did emptied at the beginning of the search  but it isn't working at all. You can check the link in the question above.

Comment: @PawanRai because the all the references to form the `bucket` content, are still there. E.g. `jobTitles`, `imgs`, `orgNames`, etc.. - You need to reset them too. Check again your code sample, in there I have provided your own `reset()`